# Prestashop get static token for controler

Tags: php, cron, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I am developing a module that has function that need to run periodically in cron.
The idea of implementation is to create a controller that third party cron module is going to call. My problem is that in order to call that controller a token is needed. Tokens in admin panel are temporary per session. Is there any way to get static token for a certain controller? Or is there a better way to implement what I want (through api or something)?

routes.yml:

```
admin_mymodule_myaction:
  path: /mymodule/myaction
  methods: [GET]
  defaults:
    _controller: 'PrestaShop\Module\MyModule\Controller\Admin\MyController::myAction'
```

MyController.php:

```
class MyController extends FrameworkBundleAdminController{
  public function myAction(){
    ...
  }
}
```

link to controller (token is temporary):

```
http://localhost/admin303/index.php/modules/mymodule/myaction?_token=uPmkkqeqBVfnjUGdLKs9_Ik585Q1GlsXWK-qiGfC3r0
```

Comment: some of your codes plzz

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
I need to use **Front controller**, NOT **Admin controller**. Front controller needs no token, I can define my own security system.

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/#using-a-front-controller-as-a-cron-task

mymodule/controllers/front/cron.php:

```
<?php

class MyModuleCronModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{

    /** @var bool If set to true, will be redirected to authentication page */
    public $auth = false;

    /** @var bool */
    public $ajax;

    public function display()
    {
        $this->ajax = 1;

        //my functionality goes here

        $this->ajaxDie("OK.");
    }

}
```

and the link to trigger functionality will be:

```
http://localhost/index.php?fc=module&module=mymodule&controller=cron
```

Wonder why official documentation did not come up during Google search.